# Error 500 using gin with simple GET in golang deployed service

Tags: linux, go, systemctl

Something rare is happening, the code running locally with no problems, and even run with no problems in the server when I call it using "go main.go", but after build and set the systemctl service it's throwing an error 500:

> `/home/user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/gin.g`
> `(Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)`
> `/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2879 (0x6663da)`
> `serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)`
> `/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1930 (0x661a87)` `(conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)`
> `/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm amd64.s:1581 (0x465200)` `goexit: BYTE  $0x90        // NOP` `[GIN] 2022/04/05 - 01:16:51 | 500 |    9.701693ms | IP |`

I'm using gin to handle http requests, this is a simple GET request:

```
func getAllTips(c *gin.Context) {
result := findAllTips()
c.IndentedJSON(200, result) }
```

called from main.go like this:

```
r.GET("/tips/", getAllTips)
r.GET("/tips/random", getRandomTip)
```

Does anyone knows how I can resolve this problem? Thank you all

Comment: Go is compiled language. Do not run code in production like `go run ...`. In fact do not even have Go tooling installed in production. Build code in a sane environment on a build machine and then ship only built binaries and run them via systemd.

Comment: So, the error 500 is happening because I installed the Go tooling?

Comment: I did not answer the question, just made _a comment_ about something that is wrong. You will probably need to reduce your problem to a minimal reproducible example so that people can help with it.

Comment: Can you post the entire error trace? It looks like your code panics somewhere but its hard to tell from what you posted.

Comment: Thank you, well, that is the complete text error that logger shows, and that is one of the reasons why I don't know how to solve it, I think is related with gin and  systemctl but I don't know what is exactly.

Comment: I think you should provide more error stack/log and code

Comment: Sorry, this is pretty much it shows. Could you provide me with some advice about getting more info about it?